# Integrating color picker to contact form 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, color-picker, contact-form-7

I need to a color picker to my contact form. How do i set it? If any option available to do it. Please anybody help me.

Comment: I searched on google to do it but I didn't get any solution. Is there any function available that would be great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this plugin](http://jscolor.com/).

You have to add the [script to your site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript), and then, when you create the input element in the Contact Form 7 plugin, remember to add the class `color` to it.

Example:

```
[text* selected-color 20/40 class:color "FFFFFF"]
```